My thermostat is stuck on the on mode.What do I do?It won't go to the auto mode and the fan thing
My AC unit and my thermostat is stuck on the on the fan selection. It will not go to auto what do I do.

We have no idea. Could be mis-wired or broken. Could be a problem with the thermostat or elsewhere in the heating/cooling system. Please provide more context/detail in order to allow us to answer your question.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It is possible the thermostat slide switch for on/off/auto is broken or frozen in place. You may need to replace the thermostat.
Get a new thermostat before attempting to force the slide switch as that is probably when it will break.
Then you will already have the new thermostat to replace it. If it slides and works in the auto position you can return the new thermostat. 
